# Why does TFormatSettings use incorrect ShortTimeFormat?

Tags: delphi, time, delphi-10.1-berlin

After several hours of investigations and researching the problem, I've found that `TFormatSettings` returns an incorrect `ShortTimeFormat`.

To show in `TDateTimePicker` a short time format with support for 24-hours, I need to use: `TDateTimePicker.Format :='H:mm'`, and this is a default setting for my profile in Windows 10 for a short time.

But `TFormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat` return me a value of `'h:mm'`.

To get the correct value, I should use:

```pascal
GetLocaleStr(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SSHORTTIME, '');
```

And this returns a `'H:mm'` value.

This is the source of `TFormatSettings` from `SysUtils.pas`:

```pascal
  TimePrefix := '';
  TimePostfix := '';
  if StrToIntDef(GetLocaleStr(Locale, LOCALE_ITLZERO, '0'), 0) = 0 then
    HourFormat := 'h'
  else
    HourFormat := 'hh';
  if StrToIntDef(GetLocaleStr(Locale, LOCALE_ITIME, '0'), 0) = 0 then
    if StrToIntDef(GetLocaleStr(Locale, LOCALE_ITIMEMARKPOSN, '0'), 0) = 0 then
      TimePostfix := ' AMPM'
    else
      TimePrefix := 'AMPM ';
  Result.ShortTimeFormat := TimePrefix + HourFormat + ':mm' + TimePostfix;
  Result.LongTimeFormat := TimePrefix + HourFormat + ':mm:ss' + TimePostfix;
```

As we can see, that always use `'h'` or `'hh'`, no way to get `'H'` or `'HH'`.

My question is: Why?

Comment: First nothing in that has changed for Rio, then there is this: [RSP-20159](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20159)
>it completely ignores LOCALE_SSHORTTIME and LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT

Comment: Why is because there's a bug (which is clearly seen in the code you posted). We can't fix bugs in the Delphi RTL, because this is SO and not EMBT. The bug still exists in Rio, as @FredS has pointed out with the link to the bug report. You can either wait for a fix to come out from EMBT (maybe in the next release, maybe not) or create your own TFormatSettings in your app startup and set it the way you want it to be set.

Comment: Or you can add a copy of `System.SysUtils.pas` to your project and then modify the buggy implementation yourself to make `TFormatSettings` do the right thing. And then if/when EMBT finally fixes it properly, you can just remove the `System.SysUtils.pas` copy from your project.